# what is a scalar implementation in elliptical curve cryptography?

Tags: elliptic-curve

I'm trying to learn the basics of elliptical curve cryptography
and would like to know the difference between scalar and non
scalar.

The test example that comes with the library creates key pairs
performs signing and verification both for scalar and non-scalar,
what is the difference ?

The function in question is:

```
    void ed25519_add_scalar(unsigned char *public_key, unsigned char *private_key, const unsigned char *scalar)
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? These are not usual terms.

Comment: I suppose you're speaking of scalar multiplication but really there no such thing as "non-scalar" multiplication so I think you're just making word salad of various unrelated things you've stumbled across.